# Javascript passing parameters to function

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

Rookie question: I have the following JavaScript functions. This works correctly but I don't want to hardcode the strings "Names" and "namesDiv". I want to pass them in as parameters to the getItems().How do I do this?

Edit: The function GetMsg() returns a JSON object: result.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="getItems(); return false;" value="Go"/>
```

JS:

```
function getItems() {
   loadingMsg();
   GetMsg("Names", null, callback);
}

function callback(result, args){
   clearContainer();
   //do stuff
   document.getElementById("namesDiv").append(foo);
}

function loadingMsg(){
    clearContainer();
    // do stuff
    document.getElementById("namesDiv").append(foo);   
}

function clearContainer(){
    document.getElementById("namesDiv").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For half of them, it's obvious; you just start passing the parameters to the function:

```
function loadingMsg(containerID) {
    clearContainer(containerID);
    document.getElementById(itemDiv).append(foo);   
}

function clearContainer(containerID) {
    document.getElementById(containerID).innerHTML = "";
}
```

`callback` is a little more complex. We'll turn it into a function returning the callback.

```
function makeCallback(containerID) {
    function callback(result, args) {
        clearContainer();
        document.getElementById(containerID).append(foo);
    }
    return callback;
}
```

Now we can call `makeCallback` to get a callback. We can now write `getItems`:

```
function getItems(itemType, containerID) {
   loadingMsg(containerID);
   GetMsg(itemType, null, makeCallback(containerID));
}
```

Comment: @icktoofay Exactly what I needed. Thanks! @Pablo Fernandez Sorry I should have explained better in my question.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply:

#### HTML

```
<input type="button" onclick="getItems('Names', 'namesDiv'); return false;" value="Go"/>
```

#### JS

```
function getItems(name, div) {
    loadingMsg();
    GetMsg(name, null, function(r, args) { callback(div, r, args); });
}
```

*EDIT:* I think I've covered everything...

Answer (score 1):

```
 onclick="getItems('namesDiv', 'Names'); return false;"
```

and then:

```
function getItems(param1, param2) {
```

`param1` will be `namesDiv` and `param2` will be `Names`

This said, I'd recommend you take a look at [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_behavior_from_markup) especially the part that talks about separation of behavior from markup.

Comment: That doesn't answer the whole question; there are other uses of `"Names"` and `"namesDiv"` outside of `getItems`.

Comment: __do read__ the question. It's " I want to pass them in as parameters to the getItems().How do I do this?". The OP probably copied the whole js for completeness

Comment: Yes, but callback will not be in scope and will not know what 'namesDiv' is.

Comment: I **did read** the question. Sure, they wanted to pass them in as parameters, but they probably wanted the arguments to apply to the other functions as well.

Comment: Fair enough. Anyway since this answers the question I'll let the OP decide if this is enough or he needs more guidance (your answer can help him in that case)

Answer (score 0):

use `addEventListener` instead of inline `onclick`

```
<input type="button" id="getItems" value="Go" />
```

JS:

```
function getItems(name, id) {
   loadingMsg(id);
   GetMsg(name, null, callback(id));
}

function callback(id){
    return (function() {
        function(result, args){
           clearContainer(id);
           //do stuff
           document.getElementById(id).append(foo);
         }
    })();
}

function loadingMsg(id){
    clearContainer(id);
    // do stuff
    document.getElementById(id).append(foo);   
}

function clearContainer(id){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("getItems").addEventListener("click", function() {
        getItems("Names", "namesDiv");
    }, false);
}, false);
```