# sessionStorage doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, session-storage

this problem look easy yet unsolved by me.

i have javascript code like this to stores data for one session :

```
function colorRed() {
document.getElementById("dashboard").style.backgroundColor = "#D64541";
document.getElementById("picked").style.backgroundColor = "#D64541";
document.getElementById("logout").style.color = "#D64541";
sessionStorage.setItem('colRed', "#D64541");
}
colorRed(sessionStorage.getItem('colRed'));

function colorGreen() {
document.getElementById("dashboard").style.backgroundColor = "#2ECC71";
document.getElementById("picked").style.backgroundColor = "#2ECC71";
document.getElementById("logout").style.color = "#2ECC71";
sessionStorage.setItem('colGreen', "#2ECC71");
}
colorGreen(sessionStorage.getItem('colGreen'));

function colorBlue() {
document.getElementById("dashboard").style.backgroundColor = "#6BB9F0";
document.getElementById("picked").style.backgroundColor = "#6BB9F0";
document.getElementById("logout").style.color = "#6BB9F0";
sessionStorage.setItem('colBlue', "#6BB9F0");
}
colorBlue(sessionStorage.getItem('colBlue'));
```

Those function will change the `background` and `font` color by button. And thats work perfectly what i want, but.. The problem is when i try to refresh the page, the color change back to default color i use in `css`.

This is the `html` code :

```
<div id="dashboard" class="dashboard">
 <img src="assets/img/svg/029-crown.svg" class="rank"/>
 <h2><?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></h2>
 <a id="logout" href="logout" class="logout">Logout</a>
 <div id="picked" class="color">
  <div id="choose" class="color-container">
   <div id="red" onclick="colorRed()" class="red color-pick"></div>
   <div id="green" onclick="colorGreen()" class="green color-pick"></div>
   <div id="blue" onclick="colorBlue()" class="blue color-pick"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Question is : 
1. Why `sessionStorage` not working 
2. Does `css transition` affected to `sessionStorage` ? Why am i asking this, because before i'm using `css transition` the `sessionStorage` work perfectly.

Thanks..

Comment: You're passing `sessionStorage.getItem('colRed')` to your `colorRed()` function as an argument, but you've not defined an argument to your function.

Comment: You do nothing with it.....

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan What should i do ?

Comment: @epascarello seems quietly right, but its unsolved yet, can you please help me ? :(

Comment: What do you think `colorRed(sessionStorage.getItem('colRed'));` is doing? It calls the color function, and if this is in the head, you are calling the color methods before the elements are even rendered to the page.

Comment: you should `setItem` with the same key like `theme` and onload `getItem` theme and apply it

Comment: You should do some research on how to pass parameters to a function in JavaScript ([here's a SO question about that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6638088/215552)). Maybe take a couple of tutorials on how to write JavaScript. This is basic programming.

Comment: @epascarello oh yaa, i get it.. Thanks for remind me :D

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Need to take a coffee before continue coding, i solved this by myself with your help, thanks!

Comment: @taguenizy yeaa thanks bro ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use one function to set all colors, and pass a color variable to it. To initiate a color, you need to get the color value you stored in the sessionStorage and set the background color before the page loads. E.g.

```
// Generic function to set background color
function setColor(color) {
  document.getElementById("dashboard").style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.getElementById("picked").style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.getElementById("logout").style.color = color;
  sessionStorage.setItem('bgColor', color);
}

// Set color to initial color if it exists
var storedColor = sessionStorage.getItem('bgColor');
if (storedColor != undefined) setColor(storedColor);
```

And then, change your button function calls to something like:

```
<div id="red" onclick="setColor('#D64541')" class="red color-pick"></div>
<div id="green" onclick="setColor('#2ECC71')" class="green color-pick"></div>
<div id="blue" onclick="setColor('#6BB9F0')" class="blue color-pick"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks sir :D Lot helped