# JavaScript passing values between functions

Tags: javascript, function

I have to functions, one is within an external js file named "london.js" and one is within a HTML script.

I wish to take a value from the external file and insert it into my HTML script function.

```
   function initMap(cityLatLng) {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: ldn,
}

  function loadLondon() {
      var ldn = {lat: 51.5, lng: -0.1}
}
```

I am not sure how to pass values through functions, I have tried putting the variable outside the function but it didn't work. I wish to make use of the var ldn in initMap.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pass it when you call it? unclear what you really want.

Comment: I see *two* functions with no calls to either. Please edit your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript passing parameters to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638088/javascript-passing-parameters-to-function)

Comment: Which one is your external? And which one is your embedded script? Do you have control over the external script? Are you able to make changes to it?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck initMap is internal and loadLondon is external, I am able to make changes to both, I just wish to make use of that variable within the other function

Comment: @Overtime One option would be to create a global namespace via your external script. And then access your global function via your HTML file. Assuming your external script loads before your embedded script.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript

And some other options worth looking into would be module loading, or using something like jQuery widget library.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to return that variable `ldn` and assign it to the property `center`:

```
function initMap(cityLatLng) {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 12,
  center: loadLondon(),
}

function loadLondon() {
  var ldn = {lat: 51.5, lng: -0.1};

  // your logic with ldn;

  return ldn;
}
```

Comment: Although this sounds good in theory, the word `load` in the function makes me wonder if it's being loaded asynchronously, in which case, there is a lot more work to do.

Comment: @Ele there are other functions that may need to fill 'center' with other coordinates, such as a function named loadCardiff in the external file

Comment: Please add more code to understand the whole context.